# Paying Tax on Stocks Trading

Tags: taxes, stocks, international-trading

I'm not American Citizen and I don't live in the USA and I want to open an account on TD Ameritrade to trade on Stocks, my question is that, do I have to pay Tax in the USA for the stock trading with TD Ameritrade?

If I have to pay tax in the USA for trading on TD Ameritrade, would it make any difference if I trade on CMC Markets in Singapore in terms of Taxation?

Comment: Please provide detail about where you are considered resident for tax purposes.

Comment: I'm a residence of Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question doesn't depend on who you trade with but what country you live in. If you live outside of the US, you will have to pay tax on dividends... sometimes. This depends on the tax treaty that your country has with the US. Canada, Australia, UK and a few other countries have favorable tax treaties with the US that allow you to not be double taxed. You must look into the tax treaty that your home country has with the US to answer the question. Each country is different.